# Simply connected implies isomorphism of Lie algebras.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $SL(2,C)$  be a special linear group and $SO(1,3)$ the special orthogonal group. We can show that $SL(2,C)$ is a double cover of $SO(1,3)$. Now the book I am reading says that  since $SL(2,C)$ is simple connected their Lie algebras are isomorphic. Why is that simple connectedness implies Lie algebra isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

The covering map $\pi\colon SL(2,\Bbb C)\longrightarrow SO(1,3)$ induces a Lie algebra homomorphism $\pi^*\colon\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)\longrightarrow\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. Since $\pi$ is surjective, $\pi^*$ is surjective. And since $\ker\pi$ is discrete, $\ker\pi^*=\{0\}$. So, $\pi^*$ is an isomorphism.

You can also say that, since $\pi$ is a covering map, there are neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of the identity elements of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ and of $SO(1,3)$ respectively such that the restriction of $\pi$ to $U$ is a diffeomorphism from $U$ onto $V$. But then the derivative of $\pi$ at the identity element of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ is a vector space isomorphism. But this derivative is precisely $\pi^*$.

Comment: How can we proof your last sentence "Since $\pi$ is surjective, $\pi^*$ is surjective. And since $\ker\pi$ is discrete, $\ker\pi^*=\{0\}$. So, $\pi^*$ is an isomorphism."?

Comment: This follows from standard Lie theory theorems. But I've added another answer.

Comment: Could you give me a reference please?

Comment: Right now, no, I cannot.